# Misleading cell security error message prevents drillthrough action on SSAS2008

Tags: ssas, ssas-2008, drillthrough

I have a cube with no cell security configured, and get an intermittent problem with a drillthrough action.  The cube has two measure groups: One with accounting transactions from a financials application (Oracle Financials) and one with a set of FX rates.  The FX conversions are done with a measure expression, and forced to leaf level by the cube script.  This problem is taking place on SSAS2008 (R1).

```
scope ([functional currency].[functional currency].[all]);
    scope ([measures].[herp fx rate]);
        this = null;
    end scope;
    scope ([measures].[derp fx rate]);
        this = null;
    end scope; 
end scope;

scope (leaves ([functional currency]));    
    scope ([fx period].[period].members);  
        scope ({[measures].[Herp GBP]});    
            this = [measures].[accounted] * 
                   [measures].[Herp fx rate];    
            //fore_color (this) = 4227327;   
        end scope;    

        scope ({[measures].[Derp GBP]});    
            this = [measures].[accounted] * 
                   [measures].[Derp fx rate];    
             //fore_color (this) = 32768;  
        end scope;  
    end scope;     
end scope;  

Calculate;
```

The cube has a drillthrough action on it.  When I attempt a drill through action (via the SSMS cube browser, for example) the cube intermittently returns an error to the effect of

> The drillthrough operation cannot be
>   performed because cell security does
>   not allow access to the source data

Various forum postings suggest that setting IgnoreUnrelatedDimension=False will fix this.  However, I can't find any documentation that explains why this happens and the error message is somewhat unhelpful.  Does anybody have a coherent explanation of what is causing this error?

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution for this problem?

Comment: If I recall l correctly it was a data issue in the underlying cube data, and it went away by itself after an ETL run populated the underlying data mart correctly.  I think it was more of a case of a misleading error message than anything substantial.